# pouchdb not creating local DB with electron and leveldb on linux

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, pouchdb

I'm using [PouchDB](https://pouchdb.com/) to store data for my application so it works offline if needed. It works fine on my windows development machine, I had no problems creating and working with the databases.

This is my code

```
const PouchDB = require("pouchdb");
PouchDB.plugin(require("pouchdb-find"));

var productsDB = new PouchDB("DB/products"); //executing this line would immediately create a folder for my database inside the same folder as my application
```

My project folder would end up having a structure like this

```
DB
|--products
node_modules
src
package.json
```

This is my dependencies from package.json

```
"pouchdb": "^7.1.1",
"pouchdb-find": "^7.1.1",
```

Node version = 12.13.0

npm version = 6.12.0

However, when trying to run the same project on ubuntu(18.04.3) nothing happens, no folders are created for the database, no errors are log in chromes dev tools.

Am I missing something to make this work? i tried deleting my node_modules folder and installing again.

**EDIT: nevermind about my issue at the bottom, it seems i wasn't catching the errors when using promises. adding a catch logged the error to my devtools which was i was trying to destroy a non existing DB.**

<s>When i try to execute something like `.destroy()`,</s>

```
productsDB.destroy().then(() => { });
```

again nothing happens in the dev tools but there are errors logging on my terminal.

> Empty response arrived for script 'devtools://devtools/remote/serve file...

And appearing multiple times

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: Could not instantiate: ProductRegistryImpl.Registry...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out after a lot of testing with the path, it seems like linux doesn't like it if the folder doesn't exist yet. So either create the folder first or don't specify a path for the database

```
var productsDB = new PouchDB("products");
```